What is so interesting about the lagrange-newton method?
I have taken a course on nonlinear optimization. There we discussed penalty and barrier methods for nonlinear optimization. In the end my lecturer gave a short conceptual idea of SQP by introducing the lagrange-newton method were we kind of solve the equations coming from the lagrange multiplier method with the newton method.
I miss something here. I know that the KKT conditions are in general only necessary not sufficient for optimality. What is the point of finding a solution to the lagrange multiplier equations when the point doesn't need to be an optimum? I kind of don't see why this is interesting?

Any well designed solver is equipped with globalization techniques. The idea is to monitor the objective and the constraint violation at each iteration and to enforce sufficient decrease at each iteration. See for example these slides: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/362254109 (disclaimer: they're mine)

I understand that we need globalization techniques but this is not what bothers me. As far as I understand in SQP we are kind of iteratively solving the optimality conditions. What is the point of just solving the optimality conditions? If our optmization problem is not convex the KKT point we get doesn't need to be an optimum, so I don't see why I should use SQP methods for nonlinear, nonconvex functions.

Sorry, I meant that in case we have a minimization problem, the KKT point can be a local maximum or a saddlepoint when the problem is non convex.

The point of the Lagrange equations is that they are completely unconstrained and hence even the fact that you can use a performant method like Newton at all is better than one may have hoped for
